# Exotic principal ideal domains

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, examples

Recently I realized that the only PIDs I know how to write down that aren't fields are $\mathbb{Z}, F[x]$ for $F$ a field, integral closures of these in finite extensions of their fraction fields that happen to have trivial class group, localizations of these, and completions of localizations of these at a prime. Are there more exotic examples? Is there anything like a classification?

Comment: Germs of holomorphic functions at some $z_0\in\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: More generally, there are lots of discrete valuation rings arising from geometry (local ring of the generic point of a divisor in a smooth variety); I don't suppose they count as "exotic".

Comment: Dear Laurent, I don't think you can say "more generally" because Kevin's example consists of convergent power series, whereas yours are of algebraic nature. 

Comment:  As an aside (that absolutely doesn't answer the question ...) let me recall that between the innocent-looking  rings $\mathbb Z$  and $\mathbb Q$  there is a continuum of rings, all of them principal ideal domains, obtained by inverting arbitrary subsets of the prime numbers 

Comment: Yes, this is covered by "localizations of these."

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, to the best of my knowledge there is nothing like a general classification of PIDs.  Despite their easy definition, they turn out to be rather a finicky class of rings, as for instance Gauss conjectured that there are infinitely many PIDs among rings of integers of real quadratic fields, but more than $200$ years later we have not been able to prove that there are infinitely many PIDs among rings of integers of *all* number fields.  And, as came out in the comments to Emil's answer, the property of being a PID is not first order, so is not very robust in a model-theoretic sense.  In that regard, the better class of rings are the [Bézout domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout_domain), i.e., domains in which every finitely generated ideal is principal.  A theorem of Kaplansky which can be used to show that various "big" domains (e.g. $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$, the ring of all algebraic integers) are Bézout can be found at the end of the section on overrings in [these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral.pdf).  (I am now giving less precise citations to my often-changing commutative algebra notes in the hope that they will take longer to become obsolete.)

There are some interesting papers on construction of PIDs with various properties.  The one I want to read next is [this 1974 paper of Raymond C. Heitmann](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/euclid.dmj/1077310578): given any countable collection $\mathcal{F}$ of countable fields containing only finitely many fields of any given positive characteristic, Heitmann constructs a countable PID of characteristic $0$ with residue fields precisely the elements of $\mathcal{F}$.

**Added**: note that $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ is also an **antimatter domain**, i.e., it has no irreducible elements (which specialists in the field tend to call "atoms").  Thus this gives an example of a Bézout domain which is not an ultraproduct of PIDs.

Comment: With regards to Bézout domains that are not (elementary submodels of) unltraproducts of PIDs, an example which I think is easier to verify is `$R=\bigcup_nF[x^{1/n}]$`, where $F$ is a field. $R$ is Bézout because any its finitely generated subring is contained in some $F[x^{1/n}]$, which is a PID. OTOH, $x$ is not a unit in $R$, but it has no prime divisor.

Comment: I see. I suppose all the PIDs I care about are Noetherian anyway, so I am totally okay with taking the perspective that Bezout domains are the more fundamental concept. 

Comment: All PIDs are Noetherian. A Bezout domain is Noetherian iff it is a PID.

Comment: Agh, yes, what I meant to say was "all the Bezout domains I care about are Noetherian anyway."

Comment: As soon as I saw the word "finicky" I knew this was one of yours, Pete.

Comment: @JSE: Really?  Do I use the word "finicky" a lot?  Or is it just the kind of word I would use?  (If so, you must know me pretty well...)

Comment: Dear Pete, do you have a reason to link to commutative algebra notes (integral.pdf) different from those one finds on your webpage (integral2015.pdf) ?

Answer (score 15):

[Smith](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jabr.1993.1154) constructed a PID which is a nonstandard model of open induction. That should be exotic enough. (Note that nonstandard models of just slightly stronger theories of arithmetic, such as $IE_1$, are never even UFDs.)

Comment: Nice. I suppose I can also take ultraproducts of PIDs to get more exotic ones... 

Comment: Not really. In almost any nontrivial case, an ultraproduct will contain an infinite chain of divisors, and thus fail to be a UFD.

Comment: Oh, I see. Being a PID is not a first-order property. My mistake. 

Comment: @Qiaochu: right.  The corresponding first order property is that every finitely generated ideal is principal -- i.e., Bezout domains.  In other words, every ultraproduct of Bezout domains is Bezout.  Off the top of my head, I wonder whether every Bezout domain is an ultraproduct of PIDs?

Comment: @Pete: No. PIDs have additional first-order properties that do not hold for every Bézout domain, for example: every non-unit is divisible by a prime. BTW, being a PID is not a first-order property, but it's not that bad: it's expressible in $L_{\omega_1\omega}$.

Answer (score 15):

Fontaine's ring $B_{cris}^{\varphi=1}$ is a PID, and no expert in the field would have bet on it in the first place (this led to some very nice recent developments by Fargues and Fontaine).

http://www.math.u-psud.fr/~fargues/Courbe.pdf

Comment: Care to provide a definition or a reference? 

Comment: Dear Qiaochu, for a careful definition, you can have a look at this set of notes of Brinon and Conrad: http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/notes.pdf But beware that the definitions are rather technical and for many purposes, it's enough to know the main properties of the period rings. For an overview, have a look at David Savitt's notes from the POSTECH winter school: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1164264/korea_savitt.pdf (probably not a very permanent link)

Comment: I would like to add: this fact was truly an absolute shock to specialists in $p$-adic Hodge theory (including Fontaine, who invented the theory!), and the developments that it has led to are indeed *very* nice (and very recent, with hopefully more to come!).

Comment: For example, starting with this PID, one can produce a Dedekind scheme $X$ over $\mathbb Q_p$ which is infinite type, but which otherwise behaves as if it were proper, and for which $\Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X) = \mathbb Q_p$!  So it really look an enormous infinite type version of $\mathbb P^1$ over $\mathbb Q_p$.  And it is huge (!): a typical residue field of a closed point is $\mathbb C_p$.

Comment: "really look an enormous" --> "really looks like an enormous" 

Answer (score 4):

A commutative algebra is a PID if and only if it is a UFD and all nonzero prime ideals are maximal. This leads to an interesting method to construct PID's: Let $R$ be a UFD and let $S \subset R$ be a multiplicative set such that, for any prime $\mathfrak{p} \subset R$ of height $\geq 2$, there is some $f \in S$ with $f \in P$. Then $S^{-1} R$ will be a PID, because localizations of UFD's are UFD's and the poset of prime ideals in $S^{-1} R$ is obtained from the poset of prime ideals in $R$ by deleting those ideals containing an element of $S$.

This can be useful for building counterexamples, because $S^{-1} R$ is the forward limit of $f^{-1} R$ over all $f \in S$, and each of the $f^{-1} R$ will be a UFD but not a PID, so one can take counterexamples in UFD's and make them into PID counterexamples by this trick. Speaking vaguely, although $S^{-1} R$ has Krull dimension $1$, it often acts more like a ring of dimension equal to the Krull dimension of $R$.

I learned about this construction from Grayson's paper "[$SK_1$ of an interesting principal ideal domain](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049(81)90089-X)". The PID in question is to take $R = \mathbb{Z}[T]$ and $S = \{ T \} \cup \{ T^n-1 : n > 0 \}$, and the interesting property is that $SL_n(S^{-1} R)$ is **not** generated by elementary matrices.

I can't resist showing off: After I read Grayson's paper, I come up with the following simpler example. Let $R = \mathbb{R}[x,y]$ and let $S$ be the set of nonzero polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[x^2+y^2]$. Then $S^{-1} R$ is a PID by the above argument. I claim that $M= \left[ \begin{smallmatrix} x/(x^2+y^2) &y/(x^2+y^2) \\ -y&x \end{smallmatrix} \right]$ is not a product of elementary matrices. Suppose that $M=E_1 E_2 \cdots E_n$. Then the denominators of the $E_j$ only contain finitely many elements of $S$, so all the $E_j$ lie in $f(x^2+y^2)^{-1} R$ for some nonzero polynomial $f$. Choose some real number $r$ so that $f(r^2) \neq 0$, then each of the $E_j$ is a well defined continuous function on the circle $x^2+y^2 = r^2$. So $M=E_1 E_2 \cdots E_n$ gives a map from this circle to $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$. Consider the  class of this map in $H_1(SL_2(\mathbb{R})) \cong \mathbb{Z}$. Rescaling each off diagonal entry of the $E_j$ by a real number $t$ and sliding $t$ from $1$ to $0$ is a homotopy to the trivial map, so this class is $0$. On the other hand, $\left[ \begin{smallmatrix} x/(x^2+y^2) &y/(x^2+y^2) \\ -y&x \end{smallmatrix} \right]$ represents the generator of $H_1$, a contradiction. The same argument shows that the block matrix $\left[ \begin{smallmatrix} M & \\ & \mathrm{Id}_{n-2} \end{smallmatrix} \right]$ in $SL_n(S^{-1} R)$ is also not a product of elementary matrices (this time we have $H_1(SL_n(\mathbb{R}))\cong H_1(SO_n(\mathbb{R})) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2$, and we need spin groups to compute the class in $H_1$, but I think it still works.).

Comment: I love how a little topology can go a long way in algebra.

Answer (score 3):

Dear Qiaochu, if $A$ is a discrete valuation ring and if $B$ is an étale algebra over $A$, then $B$ is a discrete valuation ring. In a related vein, the henselization of a discrete valuation ring $A$ is a discrete valuation ring $A^h$ (however  it is not étale over $A$, for example because it is not finitely generated ).If $A$ is the local ring of a point on a curve in the Zariski topology, then $A^h$ is the local ring of that point in the étale topology.

A very concrete example: the henselization of the local ring $A=\mathcal O_{\mathbb A^1,0}$ of the complex affine line at the origin is the subring of the ring of formal series $\mathbb C [[T]]$ consisting of those series that are algebraic over $A$.

These seem to be examples not on your list, but I'll let you be the judge of their exotism....